# How can I turn an existing Swift textLabelOutlet into a SpriteKitNode to have particle effects emit from it?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit, storyboard

So in my project I have a GameViewController made in Storyboards with labels that have constraints and it looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController, UIProtocol {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var currencyAmountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var energyLabel: UILabel!
    
    let gameBrain = GameBrain()

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = SKView()
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        gameBrain.uiDelegate = self
        loadSpriteKit()
    }
    
    func loadSpriteKit() {

        var energyLabelNode = SKEmitterNode()
        var currencyAmountLabelNode = SKEmitterNode()

        let skView = SKView(frame: view.bounds)

        let position1 = skView.convert(energyLabel.frame.origin, from: view)
        let position2 = skView.convert(currencyAmountLabel.frame.origin, from: view)
        
        energyLabelNode.position = position1
        currencyAmountLabelNode.position = position2
        
        let scene = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size)
        scene.addChild(energyLabelNode)
        scene.addChild(currencyAmountLabelNode)
       
        skView.presentScene(scene)
        view.addSubview(skView)        
    }
}
```

I am trying to turn my "labelOutlets" into nodes to add particle effects and emitters to. When this view does load I am getting the error: 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on the lines `let position1 = skView.convert(energyLabel.frame.origin, from: view)` and `let position2 = skView.convert(energyLabel.frame.origin, from: view)`

I am trying to turn the labels into nodes with the `loadSpriteKit()` function in my `viewDidLoad()`

Not really sure where to go from here and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you initialize `energyLabelNode` and `currencyAmountLabelNode`? Nothing you posted ever creates the nodes.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change my previous comment. You need to create the node before  you can use them.

Comment: Just edited it to initialize those SKEmitterNodes in the ```loadSpriteKit()``` function  which gets called during ```ViewDidLoad()```. Still getting the error that it's getting nil when the view actually loads on my phone.

Comment: energyLabel and currencyAmountLabel are still set up as UILabels, defined as implicitly unwrapped optionals. If you removed those labels in your storyboard, they will always be nil, so your code that tries to reference energyLabel will crash. Convert your UILabel IBOutlets to regular optionals (`@IBOutlet weak var currencyAmountLabel: UILabel?`)

Comment: @DuncanC So I made my label outlets optionals and it is no longer crashing when the view gets presented. My ```position1``` and ```position2``` lines now look like this: ```let position1 = skView.convert(energyLabel?.frame.origin ?? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), from: view)``` and I now have a gray skview covering up what the previous UI looked like. I also tried changing the ```SKView.backgroundcolor = ``` to ```.clear``` and the ```scene.backgroundcolor = ``` to ```.clear```.